# BizTalk send port using WCF-OracleDB to perform procedure call gives no-clue error messages

Tags: oracle, biztalk

Trying to debug database updates using a stored procedure in package in Oracle database. Gives following error in event log:

```
Microsoft.ServiceModel.Channels.Common.TargetSystemException: ORA-06550: line %s, column %s:
%s ---> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-06550: line %s, column %s:
%s
```

Googling for a while leads you to the fact that this is usually a compilation error. However, procedure compiles OK, and the adapter is well tested and is probably not the cause of this problem. I was able to run the procedure using direct call, but that is not the same to running from Send Port and the WCF-OracleDB adapter.

I was troubleshooting by disabling functionality part-by-part, but I still got the same error message back from Oracle.

I then stumbled across some article discussing Ambient transactions and Oracle...

Answer (score 0):

I disabled Ambient transaction in binding properties, and then I got a readable error message pointing me in the right direction.

Seems like Oracle uses other code when the transaction handling is handled from outside...?